# Parse query with typescript

Tags: typescript, parse-server

Im using typescript in the cloud code of my parse server but Im getting some problems saving and getting objects.

In the main.js file I have registered the next class:

```
Parse.Object.registerSubclass('Subscription', Subscription);
```

Subscription.ts:

```
export class Subscription extends Parse.Object {...}
```

Saving a object like:
`obj = new Parse.Object(Subscription)` it is going to create a class "undefined" storing there the data.

But typing `obj = new Parse.Object("Subscription");` its work ok.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using `new Subscription()` and followed the JS guide: http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#objects

Comment: Yes, my fault , with new Subscription works

Comment: So it’s how it should be

Comment: Yes, if you want to answer it Im going to mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using classes extending Parse.Object, you'll need to create new instances of those objects directly:

```
export class Subscription extends Parse.Object {
  constructor() {
    // Pass the ClassName to the Parse.Object constructor
    super('Subscription');
  }
}
```

> However, when using extends, the SDK is not automatically aware of
>   your subclass. If you want objects returned from queries to use your
>   subclass of Parse.Object, you will need to register the subclass,
>   similar to what we do on other platforms.

```
// After specifying the Subscription subclass...
Parse.Object.registerSubclass('Subscription', Subscription);
```

See http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#objects for more informations